# How can I detect the most inner array keys of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
array(1) {
  ["farm"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["folder1"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["horse"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["fred.jpg"]=>
        string(30) "farm/folder1/horse/fred.jpg"
      }
      ["cat"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["john.jpg"]=>
        string(28) "farm/folder1/cat/john.jpg"
      }
    }
    ["folder2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["cat"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["sam.jpg"]=>
        string(27) "farm/folder2/cat/sam.jpg"
        ["cat"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["john.jpg"]=>
          string(32) "farm/folder2/cat/cat/john.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to detect only the most inner array keys?

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
   if ($key == $most_inner_array) {
     echo $key;
   }
}
```

So that in this case the result would be:

```
fred.jpg
john.jpg
sam.jpg
john.jpg
```

Comment: I always wonder why would you guys want to do such things.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Why is this unusual for you?

Comment: I don't know, I just don't picture a scenario where this would be necessary. I'm just a very curious person.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes this looks like a file system, you want to catch every files, not folders

Comment: @Random Yes exactly!

Comment: @jeroen Good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through your array recursively and print the key if the value is not an array.

In case of just printing a value like in your example, you can do it with just [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) without any condition. Something like:

```
array_walk_recursive($your_array, function($value, $key) {
    echo $key . "\n";
});
```